# Ruby if/elseif coding error

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I'm writing a simple and small program in Ruby to output the ordinal of a number based on user input. Here is what I wrote:

```
puts "Enter a number"
number = gets.chomp.to_i

conversion = number % 10

if number == 11 || number == 12 || number == 13
  puts "That is #{number}th"

end

if conversion == 1
  puts "That is #{number}st"
elsif conversion == 2
  puts "That is #{number}nd"
elsif conversion == 3
  puts "That is #{number}rd"
else 
  puts "That is #{number}th"

end
```

As my code shows, I wanted to take the "number" from the user input, cut off the last number, and use that single digit number to determine whether "number" should be a (fir)st, (seco)nd, (thi)rd, or (four)th type of ordinal. The "conversion" value should convert that for me. However, it can be seen that the numbers 11, 12, and 13 are exceptions. My program works fine except that when I input one of these three values, I get two outcomes, not one, in the terminal such as:

```
That is 11st
That is 11th
```

My intention is that "11th" should be displayed, not "11st". Even though I tried to write an exception into my code, the "conversion" still gets executed. I'm not sure what error I made, but is there a way I can isolate the first if statement, so that my conversion does not include 11, 12, and 13?

Comment: `end [...] if conversion == 1` should probably be `elsif conversion == 1`.

Answer (score 3):

That is exactly how you have the program written!

If the number is 11,12,13 it will trigger the first if statement, as you expect it to. It will then go to the next if statement because it doesn't have any reason to end. `puts` is not a return/break statement (a return/break statement would break this code, but that is a different problem) so code will continue to run until the end.

The easiest solution would be to simply combine the two if statements into your main if/else statement:

```
if number == 11 || number == 12 || number == 13
  puts "That is #{number}th"
elsif conversion == 1
  puts "That is #{number}st"
elsif conversion == 2
  puts "That is #{number}nd"
elsif conversion == 3
  puts "That is #{number}rd"
else
  puts "That is #{number}th"
end
```

This will prevent any number from being able to be true in different if loops.